# How to identify when select option was selected (not necessarily changed)?

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

The [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/UamR7/) displays the new selected value **if it is different from the current value**:

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value='123'>123</option>
    <option value='456'>456</option>
    <option value='789'>789</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() { alert($(this).val()); });
});
```

I would like to display the value whenever an option selected (**even if it is the currently selected value**).

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook on the `click` event. It'll be a bit more often fired, but that's the best you can get.